# Installing GDAL 2.1 64-bit for Python 2.7, Windows 7

Tags: python-2.7, 64-bit, gdal

Ah, yes, back to the joy of installing GDAL.

This time, I need to install GDAL 2.1 for Python 2.7, 64-bit, on Windows 7. I used these installers for the [Python bindings](http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1500-x64-gdal-2-1-0-mapserver-7-0-1/GDAL-2.1.0.win-amd64-py2.7.msi) and [GDAL core](http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1500-x64-gdal-2-1-0-mapserver-7-0-1/gdal-201-1500-x64-core.msi), and set the appropriate path variables. I am using [Numpy 1.10.4](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy).

In the Command Prompt:

```
gdalinfo --version
> GDAL 2.1.0, released 2016/04/25
```

In Python:

```
>>> Python 2.7.11 ... MSC v.1500 64 bit(AMD64) on win32
from osgeo import gdal
gdal.__version__
>>> '2.1.0'
```

So far, so good. But, it fails to find `_gdal_array.pyd` when trying to read a dataset to a Numpy array:

```
ds = gdal.Open("test.tif")
data = ds.ReadAsArray()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    ds.ReadAsArray()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 1825, in ReadAsArray
    import gdalnumeric
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdalnumeric.py", line 1, in <module>
    from osgeo.gdal_array import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal_array.py", line 26, in <module>
    _gdal_array = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal_array.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    import _gdal_array
ImportError: No module named _gdal_array
```

Has anyone been able to install GDAL 2.1 successfully on a 64-bit system?

Comment: Did you solved the issue ? I have the same problem

Answer (score -1):

If you downloaded from source and installed numpy just after the build. You need to rebuild e reinstall the gdal/swig/python.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It would be helpful to list step-by-step instructions to rebuild and reinstall the items you noted.